# Probability of explosion of a 100 µF, 25V capacitor when powered at 5V

Tags: electrolytic-capacitor

I have a system which uses this board: [Arceli Motor Control Speed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RHMMM9W). It's supposed to run for a maximum of 5 hours continuously.

It has an electrolytic capacitor (black vertical tube) on which is written 100 µF, 25V.

I want to know if there's any risk that this capacitor may explode? I could explain why, but I'm not sure that's relevant to the question.

I've been looking on the web for information, and had a lot of trouble finding information on this specific matter.

**What I have in mind:**

- It's not very probable that this happens, because the voltage is very low, and I learned that capacitors explode only because of overvoltage, or reverse-voltage
- This board is of low quality, generic design, so the components may be faulty, but I'm not sure of that
- The problem may not the an explosion, but may be more of a leak of chemical components

I've found some information thanks to Bard, saying that "[...] in general, it is likely to be in the range of 140-160 dB [...]" (its source is a few books I'm not sure are relevant.)

Would you have any knowledge on the probability that this might happen?

Comment: Leave it running for a day not by your ear and see if it explodes.

Comment: In addition to @DKNguyen suggestion, to complete the experiment, leave it running for a day not by your ear and see if your ear explodes.

Comment: I've never seen an e-cap that was not abused by being deliberately exposed to relatively high reverse voltage explode. Doesn't mean it couldn't happen, but it's certainly not a common failure mode.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its about medical issues, not electronics

Comment: wouldn't be posible to replace it by a 100uF SMD ceramic capacitor?

Comment: Now that all "medical" element is removed from the question, how long until it's reopened?

Comment: I don't understand how "how likely is it that a 100 µF capacitor charged to 5 V will explode and make a deafeningly loud noise?" is a question about medical issues rather than electronics. I do want to mention that the amount of energy stored in that capacitor is equal to the energy a penny gains by falling 2 inches. So if you try to imagine the loudest possible sound a penny could make by falling 2 inches (onto a metal cabinet, perhaps), it's pretty much impossible for the capacitor to ever make a louder sound than that, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Hi, what should I do now? I can't contact the admin that closed the question. If I put up a new question, I'm pretty sure I'll be told it's a duplicate. Nobody reopened the question even though I modified it. And the closing choice wasn't even put up for discussion even though it's debated in the comment by other people.

Answer (score 1):

The risk of a capacitor explosion causing deafness is negligible. But it's true that an aluminum can electrolytic capacitor, when it overheats (due to a short circuit, which can be caused by overvoltage or decades of degradation over time) can pop open, and some contents could leak out. A simple risk-reduction might be to squeeze a glob of ordinary silicone sealant out to cover the capacitor's can. It would probably muffle the pop and reduce the likelihood of crud being ejected.

Setting aside the capacitor issue, I wouldn't like having a circuit with a 30 watt power source next to my head/ear unless it's well protected against an overcurrent situation. A simple fuse or other circuit breaker component should be included.

Comment: I have an on/off power button. Is that enough? EDIT: I'll upvote when the reputation is high enough!

Comment: A power button is essential, but if your circuit developed a dead short, 30 watts might be enough to burn your skin or singe your hair a bit before you got to the switch. What is the power source for this circuit?

Comment: This: Auskang Power Bank, 5000 mAh, https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B08ZYPQQF9/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&th=1

Comment: I'm sorry, was it clear that the power source was 5v? I may have not be precise enough

Comment: The power bank i WAY more dangerous than a capacitor

Comment: Looks like that power bank is IEC certified and can only deliver 5V/2A (10 W). You’re ok unless the battery in the power bank is defective.

Comment: Application notes for handling capacitors are strictly against obstructing the pressure relief vents with glues of any kind which prevent their normal operation, so in case of pressure buildup, it definitely not vent safely and is more likely to explode.

Comment: Don't use bathroom silicone sealant as when that cures it releases acetic acid which corrodes the circuitry (especially the Cu in the board). Better to use silicone for fixing the capacitor on the board.

Comment: @DDuck Bathroom silicone is just regular silicone sealant with anti-mold chemicals. They both have acetic acid, in general. There may still be products without acetic acid, but in general, some other adhesives are more suitable for electronics.

Comment: You want neutral cure silicone. It doesn't produce acetic acid. And it tends to be noticeably more expensive than most silicone you find at the hardware store aka "regular silicone".

Comment: Mark, just to be sure. I understand the powerbank is a bigger problem, so, I'm going to change it for an NiMH one. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @talhos137 Yes, NiMH is generally safer than Li-ion, if you can accept the somewhat higher size and weight. LiFePO4 is another safer choice, but I've only seen them in larger power packs.

Comment: Just to be sure (and pardon me for the repetition). You say that the risk of a capacitor blowing up causing deafness is negligible. But why? Because a 100 µF capa at 5V when it explodes does at maximum a very low noise? I can't see anything on the internet that woud allow me in any way to comparing the noise of such a failure to something else. Would it sound like a normal conversation (not dangerous)? A firecracker (dangerous)? Cause I can just put some scotch above to stop the contents from flowing away

Comment: @talhos137 How many wall chargers does the average person have? Multiply that  by the population. Every one of those has one or more small electrolytic capacitors operating under similar 5V conditions. Billions of similar capacitors, yet no reports of deafness caused by capacitor explosions. Draw you own conclusion from those statistics.